# Efficient iteration with index in Scala

Tags: scala, iteration

Since Scala does not have old Java style `for` loops with index,

```
// does not work
val xs = Array("first", "second", "third")
for (i=0; i<xs.length; i++) {
  println("String #" + i + " is " + xs(i))
}
```

How can we iterate efficiently, and without using `var`'s?

You could do this

```
val xs = Array("first", "second", "third")
val indexed = xs zipWithIndex
for (x <- indexed) println("String #" + x._2 + " is " + x._1)
```

but the list is traversed twice - not very efficient.

Comment: These are all good responses. What am I missing from Java 'for' loops is the ability to have multiple initializers, and the ability to "iterate" using more than just increments/decrements. This is one instance where Java can be more concise than Scala.

Comment: ..."iterate" using more than just increments/decrements... In scala it is possible to iterate with step, or iterate with "if" condition in loop header. Or you're looking for something else?

Comment: /*Java*/ for(int i=0, j=0; i+j<100; i+=j*2, j+=i+2) {...}  How can you do this in 1 line in Scala?

Comment: @snappy : In my opinion, the most natural translation to Scala would be a `while` loop. As I recall, there was a debate some years ago whether Scala should inherit Java's `for(;;)` loop, and it was decided that the benefit was not enough to justify the added complexity.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Much worse than traversing twice, it creates an intermediary array of pairs. 
You can use `view`. When you do `collection.view`, you can think of subsequent calls as acting lazily, during the iteration. If you want to get back a proper fully realized collection, you call `force` at the end. Here that would be useless and costly. So change your code to

```
for((x,i) <- xs.view.zipWithIndex) println("String #" + i + " is " + x)
```

Comment: Nice idea, only one traversal, but it also creates n pairs, even if it does not create a new collection proper.

Comment: Quite right. Well there may be a vague hope that the JVM might optimize those creation away, but I would not count on that. I do not see a solution that would not be based on iterating on indexes then.

Comment: @snappy This one should have been chosen as an answer! Accessing elements by index, which was suggested in most other answers, violates the functional nature of Scala and performs awfully on linked lists (like `List`, the most used collection in Scala) - and not only on them. Check out the `apply` operation [over here](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html). In a linked list -like collection every access to an element by index results in a traversal of the list.

Comment: quite a different approaches are shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821194/get-index-of-current-element-in-a-foreach-method-of-traversable

Comment: Why is this efficient? it is creating a new array object, and uses an additional function (`view') so I find it hard to see why this is efficient to the developer nor the machine, aside from feeling smartly idiomatic.

Comment: @DidierDupont how to get the return value , return x is throwing error

Answer (score 77):

It has been mentioned that Scala *does* have syntax for `for` loops:

```
for (i <- 0 until xs.length) ...
```

or simply

```
for (i <- xs.indices) ...
```

However, you also asked for efficiency. It turns out that the Scala `for` syntax is actually syntactic sugar for higher order methods such as `map`, `foreach`, etc. As such, in some cases these loops can be inefficient, e.g. [How to optimize for-comprehensions and loops in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146182/how-to-optimize-for-comprehensions-and-loops-in-scala/6146626#6146626)

(The good news is that the Scala team is working on improving this. Here's the issue in the bug tracker: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4633)

For utmost efficiency, one can use a `while` loop or, if you insist on removing uses of `var`, tail recursion:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

@tailrec def printArray(i: Int, xs: Array[String]) {
  if (i < xs.length) {
    println("String #" + i + " is " + xs(i))
    printArray(i+1, xs)
  }
}
printArray(0, Array("first", "second", "third"))
```

Note that the *optional* `@tailrec` annotation is useful for ensuring that the method is actually tail recursive. The Scala compiler translates tail-recursive calls into the byte code equivalent of while loops.

Comment: +1 for mentioning indices method/function as I find it way preferable due to its virtually eliminating a whole set of off-by-one programming errors.

Comment: It must be noted here that if `xs` is of any kind of linked list (such as the widely used `List`), accessing its elements by index like `xs(i)` will be linear and thus the `for (i <- xs.indices) println(i + " : " + xs(i))` will perform way worse than even `for((x, i) <- xs.zipWithIndex) println(i + " : " + x)`, as it will result in much more than just two traversals under the hood. Therefore the answer of @didierd suggesting to use views should be accepted as the most general one and the most idiomatic one, IMO.

Comment: If maximum efficiency is needed (for example, in numerical computing) it is faster to index arrays than to traverse a linked list. The nodes of a linked list are separately heap allocated, and jumping across different memory locations doesn't play well with the CPU cache. If a `view` is used, this even high level of abstraction will put more pressure on the heap and GC. In my experience there is often a factor of 10 in performance to be gained by avoiding heap allocation in numerical code.

Comment: Hi. I am new to Scala. I would like to ask why there is no "=" when you defined your printArray() function?

Answer (score 20):

One more way:

```
scala> val xs = Array("first", "second", "third")
xs: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(first, second, third)

scala> for (i <- xs.indices)
     |   println(i + ": " + xs(i))
0: first
1: second
2: third
```

Comment: I really like your pointing out the indices method/function. It reduces complexity and virtually eliminates a whole set of "off by one" errors which is the most common programming error/bug in all of software engineering.

Answer (score 17):

Actually, scala has old Java-style loops with index:

```
scala> val xs = Array("first","second","third")
xs: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(first, second, third)

scala> for (i <- 0 until xs.length)
     | println("String # " + i + " is "+ xs(i))

String # 0 is first
String # 1 is second
String # 2 is third
```

Where `0 until xs.length` or `0.until(xs.length)` is a `RichInt` method which returns `Range` suitable for looping.

Also, you can try loop with `to`:

```
scala> for (i <- 0 to xs.length-1)
     | println("String # " + i + " is "+ xs(i))
String # 0 is first
String # 1 is second
String # 2 is third
```

Comment: `xs(i)` on lists raises complexity to O(n^2)

Comment: @Vadzim That's true, but that would also be the case in Java in you used a for loop on the indices with a LinkedList

Comment: In the case of xs(i) on Arrays, the above code is O(n), right? Since Arrays in scala offer near-constant time random access?

Comment: @dhfromkorea yes, should be fast for Arrays (indeed O(n))

Answer (score 6):

How about this?

```
val a = Array("One", "Two", "Three")
a.foldLeft(0) ((i, x) => {println(i + ": " + x); i + 1;} )
```

Output:

```
0: One
1: Two
2: Three
```

Answer (score 5):

Looping in scala is pretty simple.
Create any array of your choice for ex.

```
val myArray = new Array[String](3)
myArray(0)="0";
myArray(1)="1";
myArray(2)="2";
```

Types of loops,

```
for(data <- myArray)println(data)

for (i <- 0 until myArray.size)
println(i + ": " + myArray(i))
```

Answer (score 5):

I have the following approaches

```
object HelloV2 {

   def main(args: Array[String]) {

     //Efficient iteration with index in Scala

     //Approach #1
     var msg = "";

     for (i <- args.indices)
     {
       msg+=(args(i));
     }
     var msg1="";

     //Approach #2
     for (i <- 0 until args.length) 
     {
       msg1 += (args(i));
     }

     //Approach #3
     var msg3=""
     args.foreach{
       arg =>
        msg3 += (arg)
     }


      println("msg= " + msg);

      println("msg1= " + msg1);

      println("msg3= " + msg3);

   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, calling `zipWithIndex` on a collection will traverse it and also create a new collection for the pairs.  To avoid this, you can just call `zipWithIndex` on the iterator for the collection.  This will just return a new iterator that keeps track of the index while iterating, so without creating an extra collection or additional traversing.

This is how `scala.collection.Iterator.zipWithIndex` is currently implemented in 2.10.3:

```
  def zipWithIndex: Iterator[(A, Int)] = new AbstractIterator[(A, Int)] {
    var idx = 0
    def hasNext = self.hasNext
    def next = {
      val ret = (self.next, idx)
      idx += 1
      ret
    }
  }
```

This should even be a bit more efficient than creating a view on the collection.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing in the stdlib that will do it for you without creating tuple garbage, but it's not too hard to write your own.  Unfortunately I've never bothered to figure out how to do the proper CanBuildFrom implicit raindance to make such things generic in the type of collection they're applied to, but if it's possible, I'm sure someone will enlighten us. :)

```
def foreachWithIndex[A](as: Traversable[A])(f: (Int,A) => Unit) {
  var i = 0
  for (a <- as) {
    f(i, a)
    i += 1
  }
}

def mapWithIndex[A,B](in: List[A])(f: (Int,A) => B): List[B] = {
  def mapWithIndex0(in: List[A], gotSoFar: List[B], i: Int): List[B] = {
    in match {
      case Nil         => gotSoFar.reverse
      case one :: more => mapWithIndex0(more, f(i, one) :: gotSoFar, i+1)
    }
  }
  mapWithIndex0(in, Nil, 0)
}

// Tests....

@Test
def testForeachWithIndex() {
  var out = List[Int]()
  ScalaUtils.foreachWithIndex(List(1,2,3,4)) { (i, num) =>
    out :+= i * num
  }
  assertEquals(List(0,2,6,12),out)
}

@Test
def testMapWithIndex() {
  val out = ScalaUtils.mapWithIndex(List(4,3,2,1)) { (i, num) =>
    i * num
  }

  assertEquals(List(0,3,4,3),out)
}
```

Comment: This is something that will definitely make sense to be added to the standard library.

Comment: I'm not so sure, since if you want to conform to the usual foreach/map APIs you're stuck with tuples anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Some more ways to iterate:

```
scala>  xs.foreach (println) 
first
second
third
```

foreach, and similar, map, which would return something (the results of the function, which is, for println, Unit, so a List of Units)

```
scala> val lens = for (x <- xs) yield (x.length) 
lens: Array[Int] = Array(5, 6, 5)
```

work with the elements, not the index

```
scala> ("" /: xs) (_ + _) 
res21: java.lang.String = firstsecondthird
```

folding

> ```
> for(int i=0, j=0; i+j<100; i+=j*2, j+=i+2) {...}
> ```
>
> can be done with recursion:

```
def ijIter (i: Int = 0, j: Int = 0, carry: Int = 0) : Int =
  if (i + j >= 100) carry else 
    ijIter (i+2*j, j+i+2, carry / 3 + 2 * i - 4 * j + 10)
```

The carry-part is just some example, to do something with i and j. It needn't be an Int.

for simpler stuff, closer to usual for-loops:

```
scala> (1 until 4)
res43: scala.collection.immutable.Range with scala.collection.immutable.Range.ByOne = Range(1, 2, 3)

scala> (0 to 8 by 2)   
res44: scala.collection.immutable.Range = Range(0, 2, 4, 6, 8)

scala> (26 to 13 by -3)
res45: scala.collection.immutable.Range = Range(26, 23, 20, 17, 14)
```

or without order:

```
List (1, 3, 2, 5, 9, 7).foreach (print)
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple and efficient way, inspired from the implementation of `transform` in [SeqLike.scala](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/SeqLike.scala#L43)

```
    var i = 0
    xs foreach { el =>
      println("String #" + i + " is " + xs(i))
      i += 1
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solutions suffer from the fact that they either explicitly iterate over a collection or stuff the collection into a function. It is more natural to stick with the usual idioms of Scala and put the index inside the usual map- or foreach-methods. This can be done using memoizing. The resulting code might look like

```
myIterable map (doIndexed(someFunction))
```

Here is a way to achieve this purpose. Consider the following utility:

```
object TraversableUtil {
    class IndexMemoizingFunction[A, B](f: (Int, A) => B) extends Function1[A, B] {
        private var index = 0
        override def apply(a: A): B = {
            val ret = f(index, a)
            index += 1
            ret
        }
    }

    def doIndexed[A, B](f: (Int, A) => B): A => B = {
        new IndexMemoizingFunction(f)
    }
}
```

This is already all you need. You can apply this for instance as follows:

```
import TraversableUtil._
List('a','b','c').map(doIndexed((i, char) => char + i))
```

which results in the list

```
List(97, 99, 101)
```

This way, you can use the usual Traversable-functions at the expense of wrapping your effective function. Enjoy!