# Scala List vs ListBuffer

Tags: scala

I am modeling a [DFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) in Scala. I have a transition matrix which is a directed acyclic graph represented as 2-D matrix (more accurately, array or arrays). I have implemented a method `getNextTransitions` which will give me the possible next states based on the current state I am in. Consider the two implementations below which give correct output but differ in data structure used.

Using [`ListBuffer`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer):

```
def getNextTransitions(currState: Int): List[Edge] = {
  val ret: ListBuffer[Edge] = ListBuffer[Edge]()
  val row: Array[Int] = transitionDAG(currState) //row is a 1-d array
  row.indices.foreach(j => {
    if (row(j) != -1) {
      ret += Edge(STATES(currState), STATES(j), row(j))
    }
  })
  ret.toList
}
```

Using [`List`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List):

```
def getNextTransitions1(currState: Int): List[Edge] = {
  var ret: List[Edge] = List[Edge]()
  val row: Array[Int] = transitionDAG(currState) //row is a 1-d array
  row.indices.foreach(j => {
    if (row(j) != -1) {
      ret = Edge(STATES(currState), STATES(j), row(j)) :: ret
    }
  })
  ret
}
```

Scala encourages using immutable data structures, but I can't find a way of replacing `var ret: List[Edge]` with `val ret: List[Edge]` in `getTransitions1` method above. Any suggestions?

Also, should I even try to force myself thinking in an alternative way when the `getTransitions` method using `ListBuffer` already does its job?

Adding definition of `State` and `Edge` classes. For the sake of simplicity, type parameters are removed in the question. So `Edge` class can be assumed to be `case class Edge (start: State, end: State, edgeVal:Any)`

`State` class:

```
case class State[+T](stateVal: T) {
  override def toString: String = {
    stateVal.toString
  }
}
```

`Edge` class:

```
case class Edge[E](start: State[Any], end: State[Any], edgeVal: E) {
  override def toString: String = {
    start + " --" + edgeVal + "--> " + end
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `folding` instead of the `foreach`?

Comment: @BrianKent Could you give an example comment or answer of doing this using `fold`? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the definition of the `Edge` class?

Comment: @Brian I have added the definition of `Edge` class, I had deliberately omitted the type parameter in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that you need indices (and hence `zipWithIndex`) at all:

```
transitionDAG(currState).zip(STATES).filter(_._1 != -1).map {
  case (row, endState) => Edge(STATES(currState), endState, row)
}
```

Just zip rows with states and filter them.

Same thing using for-comprehension:

```
for ((row, endState) <-  transitionDAG(currState).zip(STATES) if row != -1)
  yield Edge(STATES(currState), endState, row)
```

Comment: Thanks! I think the for-comprehension version is very clear on it's intent (although it might be just syntactic sugar defined over higher order functions)

Answer (score 1):

The `foreach` in this is filtering for `indices` where `row(j) != -1` and returning a new `Edge` class if so. To mimic this filter and then map behavior here is an approach to filter using the same condition and wrap the result in a `Some` class. If the condition is not met, the result is None. Using this we get a `List[Option[Edge]]`. `flatten` is then used to get results for those cases that have a value.

`row.indices.foreach...`

becomes

`row.indices.map(j => if(row(j) != -1) Some(Edge(STATES(currState), STATES(j), row(j))) else None).flatten`

This returns a new collection and the last value of the method is returned in Scala. No need to even declare `var ret: List[Edge] = List[Edge]()`

Comment: and map and flatten becomes flatMap :) Or it is possible to use for comprehensive:  for {
      r <- row
      if (r != -1)
    } yield ...

Comment: Awesome, this works. I converted it to flatMap: `val ret = row.indices.flatMap(j => if (row(j) != -1) Some(Edge(STATES(currState), STATES(j), row(j))) else None)`

Comment: @al32 How can we use for-comprehension, I need the index of current column `r` in your example. That is a reason why I do a `foreach` on `row.indices`, else I could have iterated directly over `row`

Comment: @Brian there is a typo in your answer, could you change it so I can accept the answer `j => if(row(j) != 1` should be `j => if(row(j) != -1`

Comment: @vsync You can try to use zipWithIndex

Comment: How will using `zipWithIndex` enable using `for-comprehension`? Using `zipWithIndex` and `indices` is almost equivalent. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821194/get-index-of-current-element-in-a-foreach-method-of-traversable). `indices` is a bit more concise as I do not need the tuple

Comment: case class SomeY(someVal: Int)
  case class SomeX(someVal: Int, someY: SomeY)
  def zipWithIndexInFor: List[SomeX] = {
    val row = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7).toList.zipWithIndex
    for {
      (r, i) <- row
      if (r != -1)
    } yield SomeX(r, SomeY(i))
  }

Answer (score 1):

You might try using a `fold`:

```
def getNextTransitions1(currState: Int): List[Edge] = {
  transitionDAG(currState).zipWithIndex.foldLeft(List[Edge]())({
    case (ret, (row, j)) =>
      if (row != -1) {
        Edge(STATES(currState), STATES(j), row) :: ret
      } else {
        ret
      }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with yet another variant similar to [Aivean's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32704761/2063026) which uses the [`collect`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@collectFirst[B](pf:PartialFunction[A,B]):Option[B]) method on Scala collections

```
transitionDAG(currState).zip(STATES) collect {
  case (row, endState) if (endState != -1) => Edge(STATES(currState), endState, row)
}
```